# Error mounting: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, raid, troubleshooting, synology

Several years ago I purchased a Synology NAS. I had it set up like so:

(NAS) ==> (1)(2)(3)(4)(empty)

After a while, I noticed that any drive I plugged into bay number [3] would fail after a couple of months. So I took all of my information out of the drives into a single drive. Then, I proceeded to use just 3 bays:

(NAS) ==> (1)(2)(x)(3)(empty)

Everything was working well for a while. Then the global health care crisis struck and the economy took a hit. So I can´t afford a new NAS (300-600 USD) and I was slowly saving up for a new 4TB drive. After a couple of months, disaster struck again and my NAS would not turn on.

This is how I got to this precarious situation. Now, all my data... including the files I currently need to work are unavailable to me.

So, I followed this guide: https://kb.synology.com/tr-tr/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC

At just as I was finishing the last two steps, this happened:

[image: Error!]

This is how my raid is setup:

```
root@mn-System-Product-Name:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md2
  VG Name               new_name
  PV Size               <3.63 TiB / not usable <2.38 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              951505
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          951505
  PV UUID               QNnrHQ-ADTM-vV6X-T55z-S0gV-dY6d-a2IJJC
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md3
  VG Name               new_name
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable <1.88 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476927
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          476927
  PV UUID               I7cVD6-IXR5-XRMI-PUcz-jjjo-T6tM-G50ik0
   
root@mn-System-Product-Name:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               new_name
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               <5.45 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1428432
  Alloc PE / Size       1428432 / <5.45 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               C11g9o-NsbZ-I2QP-HrLR-95xZ-Oit2-y3cjAC
   
root@mn-System-Product-Name:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/new_name/syno_vg_reserved_area
  LV Name                syno_vg_reserved_area
  VG Name                new_name
  LV UUID                xqwjv8-4ynn-T5s0-GRAq-j0Bx-Hjsy-AdewGW
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                12.00 MiB
  Current LE             3
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     512
  Block device           253:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/new_name/volume_1
  LV Name                volume_1
  VG Name                new_name
  LV UUID                Rrte8D-nVIx-8HxJ-e6Hs-LnCC-8Bch-RVr4bx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <5.45 TiB
  Current LE             1428429
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     512
  Block device           253:1
```

When I was using my NAS I had files organized somewhat like this:

1. Prints
   1.1. DRM (encrypted share)
   1.1.1. Clients
   1.1.2. Invoices
   1.1.3. Formats
   1.2. Evergreen
   1.3. Calibre
2. Music
3. Movies
4. Installers
   4.1 ISOs

Basically, my entire work flow. All my ever green notes since school that I´ve been introducing to Obsidian. All my ebooks, movies, installers, ISOs. And... finally all my home movies (sonograms of my children, birthday parties, trips, pictures...)

I tried to provide as much information and context as I could.

**Is there away to fix the current Error mounting: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, missing codepage or helper program, or other error?**